# NIST19: convert images into .csv (Python)

Tags: python, csv, dataset, mnist

I am working on a project which requires to indentify handwriting digits. I used a bit the MNIST dataset but I want to expand more; MNIST contains only numbers and [the one I want to use](https://www.nist.gov/srd/nist-special-database-19) is more complete as it contains also letters (upper and lowercase).

So, I already have a classify which use a [.csv file](https://github.com/VAUTPL/Number_Detection/tree/master/data) to "predict" the digits. I dicovered that this file only contains the images compressed into this format.

I download the NIST19 Dataset (by class) and unzipped it; there are plenty of folders containing the digits in image .png format.

Any suggestion on how to proceed ? What (I think) I need is a script which can do this "conversion"...
Tell me what you think, any phrase can be useful.

Thanks